# Transform object into a string with required pattern: Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having an object with the following structure

```
{ test1 : 3, test2: 4, test3: 5 }
```

All I need is to convert this into a string with "|" as separator between key/value pairs dynamically. Output should look like,

```
test1(3) | test2(4) | test3(5)
```

Code I tried

```js
let obj = { a: "1", b: "2", c: "3" };
let finalStr = "";
for (var key in obj) {
  finalStr = key + obj[key] + "|";
}
console.log(finalStr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this help?

```
let finalStr = Object.keys(obj).map(k => `${k}(${obj[k]})`).join(" | ")
```

What I'm basically doing is iterating over the array of keys, returned by `Object.key()`, of `obj` and mapping the values to your desired format, then I'm joining that array with the `|` delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the entries (key/value pairs) and get an array of formatted strings and join the parts with wanted separator.

```js
const
    data = { test1: 3, test2: 4, test3: 5 },
    result = Object
        .entries(data)
        .map(([k, v]) => `${k}(${v})`)
        .join(' | ');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = { a: "1", b: "2", c: "3" }
t='';
for (const property in obj) {
  t+=`${property}(${object[property]}) `;
}
console.log(t.trim().split(" ").join(" | "))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.